# Using flask to serve static files: flask doesn't recognize path and defaults to 404?

Tags: python, flask

I'm developing a quick url shortner which also returns a svg version of a QR code for the same shortened URL. I'm using flask and python

I've created a specific route in flask to serve the file and return the file for download with send_file, the file gets created in the root directory (I'll need to fix this later eventually, but that's a different problem) and is in there, but when I click the link in the front, flask defaults to the 404.

This is the download route:

```
@short.route('/<qr_file>')
def download(qr_file):
    return send_file(qr_file, as_attachment=True)
```

and here's the add_link route (creates the link, commits to db, creates the qrcode, stores it, returns short and original url to the template, along with the qr_file location for the link to download)

```
@short.route('/add_link', methods=['POST'])
def add_link():
    original_url = request.form['original_url']
    link = Link(original_url=original_url)
    db.session.add(link)
    db.session.commit()

    qr_url = pyqrcode.create(link.short_url) 

    qr_file = link.short_url + '.svg'
    qr_url.svg(qr_file, scale = 8) 

    return render_template('link_added.html', 
        new_link=link.short_url, original_url=link.original_url, qr_file=qr_file)
```

Here's the relevant  in the link_added.html:

```
            <div class="field">
                    <label class="label">New URL</label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input class="input" type="text" name="original_url" value="{{ url_for('short.redirect_url_to_url', short_url=new_link, _external=True) }}">
                    </div>
            </div>
             <div class="field">
                    <label class="label">QR Code</label>

                    <a href="{{ qr_file }}"> {{ qr_file }} </a><br>

                    <img src="{{ qr_file }}" height="90" width="106" /><br>
            </div>
```

Comment: Flask as default serve static files from folder `/static` - but only if you run it in debug mode. In normal mode it doesn't serve it because it should run with Apache/NGINX server which should serve all static files.

Comment: first check what link you get in HTML - is this absolute link starting with `/` or relative  and it is combined with current url - ie. `/add_link/<qr_file>` instead of `/<qr_file>`. Probably you should add `/` in `src="/{{ qr_file }}"` to create absolute url.